# IONIC: Shared Container Folder for DocumentProvider Extension like Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, ionic-framework, ios-extensions

I want to make a `Document Provider extension` for an app originally developed in IONIC.
I understand that I can use .xcodeproj file to open the project in XCode and then add new target for intended `extension`.
However, I'm confused about shared storage between my AppGroup (App & Extension).
According to `NSFileManager` (now FileManager), you need to store files in a shared container with group identifier.
The method to achieve this is following:-

```
func containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier groupIdentifier: String) -> URL?
```

However according to IONIC guide the files can be saved in one of these locations:-
[image]

According to IONIC Developer, the files currently reside in Document Directory of App where we need to have those files in a shared container as mentioned above.
 How can we achieve that?

FYI: I couldn't find any help on IONIC forums regarding this, and I'm following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/131668/document-provider-tutorial) tutorial for Extension development.

Comment: Do you want to ship some files with the app or you want the files to be downloaded dynamically after the app install?

Comment: No, app creates some files like notes etc. I want those files to be available to other applications of same App Group. An analogy can be dropbox or iCloud drive.

Comment: Hey @AbidHussain: have you managed to solve this?

Comment: @Nikola yeah but solutions is a hack. I used generated project and built extension with it. To copy files in shared container I wrote a class to copy contents of document directory in shared container. The routine runs with a timer and also when a new file is written in doc directory. But issue obviously was that all the code had to be re-written each time this project is regenerated. I'm not IONIC expert so I don't know if it's the case but I guess it'll be this way. let me know if you need more help.